# Ionic 5 plain javascript inline ionFocus events

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

can’t I just bind inline event on ionic component?
like:

`<ion-button id="btn-focus" ionFocus="console.log(1)" >`

it works this way though:

```
            let focusbutton = document.querySelector("#btn-focus");
            focusbutton.addEventListener("ionFocus", () => {
                console.log("focused");
            })
```

Comment: `(focus)="yourEvent($event)"`  Try This.

Comment: it's not angular, just plain javascript

Comment: I can do it this way:
```
<ion-button id="btn-focus"  onclick="console.log(2)" >
```

but how can I utilize ionic event?

Comment: Can you explain Exactly what is your Issue? Why you want focus event on button?

Comment: it's just a sample. I don't especially need this event, but option to bind for any ionic event inline in html like plain javascript event

Comment: since you somehow don't use angular, this is not possible, because the angular bindings are what enables you to bind the component functions in the HTML.

Comment: @DivisionByZero it's ionic 5, framework-less, just plain javascript, no framework supposed to be used (only if you choose you can go with react, angular, vue), but not needed at all. so in documentation page under javascript option chosen we've this same ionic properties